# How to redirect logout page in django-userena?

Tags: django, django-login

I have set `LOGOUT_URL = '/home/'` in my `settings.py` but still the logout page is redirected to the default logout page of userena.

Comment: Give us the function that makes logout action please. Have you set up LOGIN_URL?

Comment: I have setup LOGIN_URL='/home/' as well 
The logout action is called through userena

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use:

```
USERENA_REDIRECT_ON_SIGNOUT = '/home/'
```

Comment: How can i redirect to my intended page after Sign In? Can I use `USERENA_REDIRECT_ON_SIGNIN` ? @Chari

Comment: If you are not using django, you can use this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/#login-redirect-url